# Accessing large JSON file using python getting error: raise common.JSONError('Additional data')

Tags: python, json

I am parsing a large  JSON dataset(5 GB) using **ijson** package and getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "subreddit_name.py", line 9, in <module>
for prefix, event, value in parser:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ijson/common.py", line 65, in 
 parse
 for event, value in basic_events:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ijson/backends/python.py",  
 line 192, in basic_parse
  raise common.JSONError('Additional data')
  ijson.common.JSONError: Additional data
```

here is my python code :

```
import ijson

file_name="/media/RC_2015-01"

with open(file_name) as file:
    parser = ijson.parse(file)
    for prefix, event, value in parser:
        if prefix=="subreddit":
            print value
```

my json block looks like this :

> {"subreddit":"languagelearning","parent_id":"t1_cn9nn8v","retrieved_on":1425123427,"ups":1,"author_flair_css_class":"","gilded":0,"author_flair_text":"Lojban (N)","controversiality":0,"subreddit_id":"t5_2rjsc","edited":false,"score_hidden":false,"link_id":"t3_2qulql","name":"t1_cnau2yv","created_utc":"1420074627","downs":0,"body":"I played around with the Japanese Duolingo for awhile and basically if you're not near Fluency you won't learn much of anything.\n\nAs was said below, the only one that really exists is Chineseskill.","id":"cnau2yv","distinguished":null,"archived":false,"author":"Pennwisedom","score":1}

does anyone know the reason and solution for this error? 
any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is your json file a single json object, or are there multiple json objects to decode? If there is more than one object in there, you could wrap them in a list (prepending '[' , appending ']' and inserting commas if needed) and see if that works.

Comment: @Simon Fraser there is only one json object.

Comment: Check Simon point:  i think you got a bad encoding(unescape error).

Comment: @dsgdfg i am not good in either python or json  so could you tell me how to check Simon point?

Comment: Check your library(backens/python.py): Line:104 on `parse_value ` python not allowed `null`, can accept `"null"` or `'null'`. You used `"distinguished":null,` null is a variable here(not an a real `None`). @Sherlock